# how to use the 'modular-scale' ruby gem from irb?

Tags: ruby, sass, compass-sass

I'm a complete ruby newbie and am trying to understand more of the modular scale library https://github.com/scottkellum/modular-scale

I wish to test out some of the functionality in irb and here is my result:

```
>> require 'modular-scale'
=> true
>> module
module  
>> modular-scale(2)
NameError: undefined local variable or method `modular' for main:Object
    from (irb):2
>> modularScale(2)
NoMethodError: undefined method `modularScale' for main:Object
    from (irb):3
>> $ratio
=> nil
>> golden()
NoMethodError: undefined method `golden' for main:Object
    from (irb):5
```

I realise that it is a compass plugin but it would be good to run some of its functions on irb. I'm more interested in the writing and testing of compass plugins than on modular scale itself. I picked the library because I thought it looked more straight forward than others.

any help would be appreciated

### update

in https://github.com/scottkellum/modular-scale/blob/master/lib/modular-scale.rb
it supplies functions that i presume are callable from irb

```
>> bar = Sass::Script::Number.new(12)    ;; This works
=> 12

>> bar = Sass::Script::Functions.major_tenth()  ;; I thought this might work but it doesn't
NoMethodError: undefined method `major_tenth' for Sass::Script::Functions:Module
    from (irb):9
```

Comment: It's meant to be used with SASS style sheets, not from `irb`.

Comment: Yeah I would recommend checking out middleman to run something like this with SASS without a full blown rails app.

Comment: Why would you need Middleman if Compass is already involved?

Comment: @zcaudate I don't think what you're looking for is possible because a Sass function isn't a Ruby function.  Sass is simply a scripting language written in Ruby.  If you're wanting to test the output of Sass functions, try the `@debug` directive.

Comment: Those functions are to be used by Sass, not IRB.  There are 2 reasons a Sass function might be written in Ruby: the functionality cannot be achieved with Sass (eg. writing images to the file system) or the function should be accessible without having to include any files (eg. all of the Compass helper functions).

Comment: I can and am using modular-scale in compass. That is not my aim. Sass, Campass, Middleman are all libraries developed in ruby so I presume that they can all be interacted through irb. I just want to call ruby functions in modular-scale from irb, nothing else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class SassPlay
  include Sass::Script::Functions
end

SassPlay.new.double_octave
=> 4
```

The method `modular-scale()` is a [Sass function](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#function_directives) and you cannot call it from `irb`. It is a style sheet function that is parsed and executed by Sass, not by `irb`.

Sass is an interpreted language. It does not have a one-to-one relationship with ruby methods, hence you cannot access all of Sass's functionality directly from ruby nor irb.

You can look at the definition `modular-scale()` here:

https://github.com/scottkellum/modular-scale/blob/master/stylesheets/_modular-scale.scss